# How to create folders dynamically and upload artifacts in Jfrog artifactory using filespecs in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory, devops

I have a build job in jenkins which builds the project from github for any branch. package will be created in build job workspace with the version as `xxxx-yyyyy-2.15.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`.

My next artifactory push job has filespec written as below:

```
{ 
 "files": [
       {
           "pattern": "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Jobname/target/*/xxxx-yyyyy*.zip",
           "target": "libs-snapshot-local/xxxx-yyyyy/",
           "recursive": "false"
       }
    ]
}
```

Above filespec recognize the pattern and upload the zip in `libs-snapshot-local/xxxx-yyyyy/`. But I need to upload the file with folder created with version name available on the zip file `xxxx-yyyyy-2.15.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`.

Can anybody help me to create a folder dynamically with version name? any idea on how to specify target path in filespec?

Answer (score 6):

The file specs has the ability to use [placeholders](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-UsingPlaceholders) in order to create more flexible paths.
For example in your case:

```
{ 
 "files": [
       {
           "pattern": "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Jobname/target/*/(xxxx-yyyyy*).zip",
           "target": "libs-snapshot-local/{1}/",
           "recursive": "false"
       }
    ]
}
```

Please pay attention for the parentheses in the pattern and the placeholder marker {1} used in the target.