# How Do I Bundle Artifacts in JFrog Artifactory Using Filespecs?

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, devops

Trying to figure out how to get the "X.Y.Z" substituted below when not every file will have that in the name. Simple filespec:

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "artifacts/",
            "target": "repository/project/X.Y.Z/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Not all of the files have the full version number in them so I can't use a simple placeholder (per [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010177/how-to-create-folders-dynamically-and-upload-artifacts-in-jfrog-artifactory-usin)). I was wondering if there was some other way to dynamically figure out the part to replace the "X.Y.Z" using some maybe-more-complex syntax?

Comment: Since you can't conditionally replace a section in the "target" using Placeholders, perhaps you can build your File Spec to include two groups of files for upload ("files" is a list and can therefore include multiple "pattern" and "target" pairs). The first group will capture files which have the version in their name and second group will capture files which don't.

Comment: Well, maybe there's another way to do it using another "language". I thought about the tactic you mentioned but the problem is that files released at different times have different content and need to be segregated according to release number. In your example, and as far as I can tell, that second set of files will go to some "unversioned" area in Artifactory and that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about the problem a bit more it occurred to me that I could put the artifacts in a specially-named directory that I could *then* use to publish from.

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "artifacts-(*)/",
            "target": "repository/project/{1}/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tested, and that seemed to do the trick. It just required a little scripting at the end of the build to name that directory with the version number in it.